# Irreducible and prime elements at \mathbb{R}

Tags: abstract-algebra

I found a lots of materials about this problem, but can someone explain a elementary way? I cannot understand the abstract algebra thing..

For all $F(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ and $F(X)$ is irreducible, then for all $G,H \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ such that $F|GH$, $F|G$ or $F|H$ holds?

Comment: Maybe you want to think of this with $\mathbb{Z}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}[x]$. If you make this analogy, $F$ becomes a prime number. If you understand it in the case of integers it is pretty much the same thing in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ and this analogy proves to be very useful for abstract euclidean rings as well.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $F\mid GH$, but $F$ does not divide $G$.  Since $F$ is irreducible, this implies the greatest common divisor between $F$ and $G$ is 1.  So (by the Euclidean Algorithm) there exists polynomials $P,Q$ such that $PF + QG = 1$.  Multiplying this equation by $H$ gives $PFH+QGH=H$.  Since $F$ divides both terms on the left side of the equation, $F$ also divides $H$.